# JavaScript: How To Code a Heads/Tails With Specific Probability Chance Percentage?

Tags: javascript, probability, coin-flipping

I've implemented the function:

```
 function coinFlip() {
      return(Math.floor(Math.random()*2) === 0) ? 'Heads' : 'Tails';
 }
```

And it's all working fine (I already tested it).

My problem is, how do I make this function so that the probability of getting 'Heads' is 30% while the probability of getting 'Tails' is 70%?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pick a random number between 0 and 1. If the number is <0.3 it's Heads. Else, it's Tails...

Comment: Okay, but suppose that I do 10 coin flips.  I want to print out the results and by logic, 3 of those will be heads and 7 will be tails.  How do I implement that?

Comment: it is not a sure thing that 3 of those will be heads and 7 of those will be tails. Over many many repeated experiments, the average will be 3 heads and 7 will tails

Comment: "3 of those will be heads"? Um, no. 3 of those will _most likely_ be heads. Use an array

Comment: I already put them in an array.  Like I said, I tested everything out and all is working in order.  I just wanted a possible solution for how to solve a specific percentage problem.  EDIT:  I have my entire code working, I just didn't put it on here since my only problem is getting the correct percentage for the heads/tails result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function coinFlip() {
      return(Math.random() < 0.3) ? 'Heads' : 'Tails';
 }
```

Comment: Thank you.  This seems to fit what I was looking for.  I initially tried a 0.7 in there but I guess all that was left is to flip the Heads/Tails position or conversely put a 0.3.

Answer (score 1):

If one of three toss coin is head it doesn't mean that in 10 toss, there will be 3 heads.. Here is your code with 500 toss (just change the number)

```
    function coinFlip() {
          return(Math.random() < 0.3) ? 'Heads' : 'Tails'; //ofc 0.3 is 30% (3/10)
    }

 var howManyTimes=500;
 var countHeads=0; 
 for (var i=0; i<howManyTimes;i++){
     if (coinFlip()==='Heads'){
       countHeads++;
     }
 }
 alert("Heads appear "+(countHeads/howManyTimes)*100+"% of the time");
```

> "how to solve a specific percentage problem"

You can't, this is how probability works